# Why the polarity of V source changed ? (Thevenin)

Tags: thevenin

I don't understand why the polarity of the voltage source in the Thevenin equivalent circuit in the left corner is changed...

[image]

Comment: How are we to know? You don't show fig 9.43. And how do you mean changed, changed compared to what/when? (I sure can make a guess based on that fig 9.46, but you should give a complete question first.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the ground symbol as a zero-volt reference point from fig.9.46:
Point *b* is one-third of *E*.
Point *a* is one-quarter of *E*.
So point *b* is at a higher potential than point *a*.

Now on to the Thevenin equivalent circuit (fig. 9.47).
 The Thevenin circuit *doesn't use ground as a reference point*. It is perhaps a mistake to show the ground symbol in fig. 9.47, because it may have confused you. The Thevenin model must appear *between point a and point b* of fig.9.46.
Fig. 9.47 correctly shows point *b* at a higher potential than point *a*.

Comment: Right... yeah thought it's referenced to ground again, thanks.

Comment: @BigRedMachine You should accept this answer, the explanation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

glen_geek is right about voltages, the "b" voltage is 6V higher than "a" point. However the ground is not a mistake. The 3||6 Ohms branch gives an equivalent of 2 Ohms and the 4||12 Ohms give a parallel equivalent of 3 Ohms. That's the reason for the 5 Ohm resistor. If you look for the lowest impedance to the ground, from "b" to ground is only 2 Ohms while from "a" to ground is 3 Ohms. The ground is definitely on the "b" side.

Comment: The ground can be more in b-side when more = less resistance. But it's still not the same ground, there's no zero ohm connection.

Comment: @user287001 It's caled virtual or equivalent ground, but it's ground nevertheless. Have you never heard of it?

Comment: I have heard it. Virtual ground is the name of a popular method of solving opamp circuits. But there's no galvanic connection between the virtual ground node and the predefined ground which holds the ground symbol in the original schematic.